# Use taken snapshot as file in input file

Tags: javascript, html, webcam.js

I need to take a snapshot with my webcam and use the taken picture as a file into an `<input type="file">`

I managed to take the snapshot using `webcam.js`.
Now I need to set the file of my input as the snapshot I just took.

How I take the snapshot:

HTML:

```
<input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
```

JS:

```
function take_snapshot() {
            // take snapshot and get image data
            Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
                // display results in page
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
                    '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' + 
                    '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
            } );
        }
```

In the JS the `data_uri` is the base64 of the snapshot I just took.
Is there a way to use the base64 string as the input file in my `<input type="file">`?

Comment: look at this full example https://makitweb.com/how-to-capture-picture-from-webcam-with-webcam-js/

Comment: @G-Man I have already checked out the library but the problem isn't solved just with it. I found a workaround for what I had to do.